# Access AR.Drone camera with OpenCV while connected to ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, rospy, ardrone-autonomy, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having an issue where by I am unable to connect to the AR Drone camera when the drone is connected through ROS using the ardrone_autonomy ardrone.launch.

I think the issue is due to the fact that I am trying to access the drone camera through the ip address with OpenCV and Python while connected through ardrone_autonomy. Below is a code snippet of how I am accomplishing this.

```
{

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture()

video_capture.open('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')

vidWidth = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)

vidHeight = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

}
```

As you can see that I am using the IP address for the camera. This works perfectly when the drone is not connected through ros which is essentially like a webcam. My end goal is for tracking and navigation through the use of images received from the camera using OpenCV which means I will have to issue movement commands(cmd_vel) which requires a connection through ardrone_autonomy based on the images received and processed by OpenCV.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this by using the IP camera from the drone while connected to ROS?

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245548/access-ar.drone-camera-with-opencv-while-connected-to-ros/) by [pyro229](https://answers.ros.org/users/28229/pyro229/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your ultimate goal is to use ROS and  `ardrone_autonomy` to control the drone, I suggest that you capture the images through the ROS API as well (e.g. subscribe to the camera topic in your node), then use the [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) package to convert the ROS image data type (`sensor_msgs::Image`) to `cv::Mat`. The following tutorial shows how to perform that in C++: [Converting between ROS images and OpenCV images (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2